# Why does System.out.println error when I try to print with slashes?

Tags: java

Hi so we just got started in school with java and I was playing at home. I was wondering why when I made a triangle with * it worked but when I tried to use '/', '\', and '_' to make it look better, it came up with 11 errors:

```
Ra2.java:3: error: unclosed string literal
        System.out.println("   /\");
                           ^
Ra2.java:3: error: ';' expected
        System.out.println("   /\");
                                     ^
Ra2.java:4: error: illegal start of expression
        System.out.print("  /");
              ^
Ra2.java:4: error: ';' expected
        System.out.print("  /");
                  ^
Ra2.java:6: error: unclosed string literal
        System.out.println(" \");
                           ^
Ra2.java:6: error: ';' expected
        System.out.println(" \");
                                 ^
Ra2.java:7: error: illegal start of expression
        System.out.print(" /");
              ^
Ra2.java:7: error: ';' expected
        System.out.print(" /");
                  ^
Ra2.java:11: error: unclosed string literal
        System.out.print(" \");
                         ^
Ra2.java:11: error: ';' expected
        System.out.print(" \");
                               ^
Ra2.java:13: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
11 errors
```

Comment: You need to escape backslashes with another backslash: `System.out.println("   /\\");`

Answer (score 1):

This is because (According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)):

> A character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler

So `\` escapes the ending quote, causing an unclosed String. You need to do:

```
System.out.println(" /\\");
```

Comment: To clarify a bit: `'\'` is the **escape character**, and it's used for putting things into strings that otherwise would not work correctly. For example, the string `"Here is a quotation mark: " see?"` will not work correctly, because Java interprets the quotation mark in the middle *as the end of the string*. So we use `"Here is a quotation mark: \" see?"`, and get the output we expect. But **that** means that using `'\'` is impossible because it's a special character just like `'"'`! So what do we do? naturally, we escape it with the escape character: `"\\"` will output the string of just '\'